# Software suggestions to make printed chess exercises for kids

Tags: coach, diagram

I'm planning to create a bunch of printed exercises for kids of different levels. I am still searching online for ideas and software suggestion. I wonder how other coaches here have solved this problem. Which software did you use to make pages and pages of chess diagrams, say with little boxes below it for kids to enter the answer? Thanks!

ps: I have ChessBase. Researching about Latex, found something called Sribus (Although I'm yet to fully understand what it does). oh, and I don't code.

Comment: I am the owner of http://www.apronus.com/chess/wbeditor.php, a collection of tools for chess publishing. I don't have a ready made tool tailored to your exact needs but I may create one if you are interested in paying for the job.

Comment: Hmmm, the "books" tag seems slightly inappropriate. What filetype do you want your diagrams to be? If you're unsure about that, here's a list for different alternatives I found after googling the subject: http://www.enpassant.dk/chess/diaeng.htm

Comment: Using any of the diagram makers mentioned by Scounged, you can insert them into a word processor.  This makes the formatting exactly how you want it.  A better, maybe faster, option is to get some college kid to make a web page template including a FEN to diagram converter.  (I did it in about 30 minutes about 15 years ago.)  Provide the right size images and an explanation of how to read a FEN, and you should have no problems.

Answer (score 2):

Possible ideas I found when I asked the question on [Reddit r/chess](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/4vcwwz/print_chess_exercises_for_students_ideas/)

- Chessbase + Wordprocessing tool
- Lichess + Evernote clipper (or snagit, etc) + Word (Add +blog if you want the answers to be public)

Other useful links that were suggested as comments

- [Apronus Pgn viewer/editer](http://www.apronus.com/chess/wbeditor.php)
- [Free chess diagrams list](http://www.enpassant.dk/chess/diaeng.htm)